# Openstack: Can't locate log in /var/log?

Tags: openstack

From Openstack webpage, I was told that the logs are located under /var/log but I can't find any log over there.

I am using the devstack. Does anyone know if they move to another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify log directory in your devstack local.conf.
Following example is to locate logs under /opt/stack/logs/screen/

```
[[local|localrc]]
#DEST=/opt/stack
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen
```